# Какой? meaning in a specific answer

Tags: значения

What does the girl asks in below sentence? I didn't understand.

```
-Boy: ты такой красивая)
-Girl: Какой?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*It should be "так**ая**/как**ая**".*

The boy says "you are so beautiful!" and the girl asks what kind of beautiful the boy means, what kind of "so", how much "so" this "so" is. Flirting she is, I would say.

Answer (score 3):

It must be said that the phrase **ты такой красивая)** is grammatically incorrect.

The correct form MUST be *ты такая красивая* (feminine for both pronoun and adjective, if you refer to a female).

I suggest that it's kind of a joke based on a grammatical mistake with some gender association due to this mistake. The boy makes a mistake - uses masculine pronoun instead of feminine (not clear why he makes it, intentionally or not), the girl replies *какой?* (continuing to make this mistake, in her case she is doing it intentionally), thus producing some comic effect.

Answer (score 2):

The girl's question is very close in meaning to "What do you mean by this?". Possible answers she probably expects are "You have charming eyes"/"У тебя замечательные глаза", "Nice waist"/"У тебя неплохая фигура".

Note: the translated sentences above are not identic because of the difference between English and Russian languages and their traditions ("неплохая талия" is a good translation but it has slightly more sexual context, while the word "фигура" is absolutely neutral).